Thriller where a woman's new roommate is obsessed with her
Years ago I watched a thriller movie where a guy becomes obsessed with a woman. The woman advertises for a new housemate. The guy who's obsessed kills the guy she took on as a housemate and she finds out when she sees him wearing his shoes. He then keeps her locked in the house for days before she finally escapes.
I think it was from the late 80's or early 90's. Definitely wasn't Single White Female. Now that I think about it, the movie begins with the guy coming home to find that his wife/girlfriend had killed herself (he'd presumably done the same to her before moving on to the woman in question). 
Has anyone seen this movie and can remember the title?

Welcome to Movies & TV stackexchange Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), estimated year of release (or at least the year you saw it), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points. The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

Sounds like the thriller Deadbolt from 1992.

When medical student Marty Hiller (Justine Bateman) places an ad for a roommate, her ad is answered by handsome, clean-cut Alec Danz (Adam Baldwin). At first Alec seems to be a wonderful roommate; supportive, considerate and a real friend. However, Alec's affection turns to obsession as he plots to manipulate and control all aspects of Marty's life, imprison her in her own apartment and make her his.

He kills one of the men she interviews and takes his shoes. And in the beginning, he comes home and finds his wife had killed herself. Here's the trailer:



